# How can i make the PC make a 'beep' sound when network cable is unplugged?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, networking, 12.10, bash

How can i make beep sound in the PC when the network cable is unplugged or no network available to any specific interface such as eth0 or eth1?

Follow up:

```
$ sudo apt-get install beep
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf | grep 'pcspkr'
blacklist pcspkr
$ sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
#blacklist pcspkr
:wq
$ sudo modprobe pcspkr
$ beep
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not going to want to keep wgetting infinitly to know if you have network:
what you are looking for is a "post-up" script. This is kinda advanced, but you should be able to do this.

First, figure out how to make a sound. You can use the methods @iUngi uses, like `echo -e` or `beep`.

To actually add this beeping to the point where you have network, use the information at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OnNetworkConnectionRunScript

The part you are interested in (but read the whole thing!) is this:

> Edit the text configuration file /etc/network/interfaces and add one
>   of the following directive pre-up , post-up , pre-down , post-down to
>   the appropriate network connection, for example :
>
> auto eth0
>   iface eth0 inet dhcp
>   name WiFi
>   post-up
>   /etc/network/if-up.d/myscript.sh
>
> restart your network:
>
> /etc/init.d/networking restart

You can obviously add an extra check ping for instance or just get the headers (`curl --head`) if your connection isn't always on *internet* but can be a local connection (and you don't want a beep then), but I think that shouldn't be needed in all cases.

Comment: This is nice post-up and post-down options. that is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following script:

```
wget --spider http://www.google.com
if [ "$?" != 0 ]; then  
   echo -e '\a'
fi
```

This check whether the google is reachable or not. If not then beep ones. You can use a while cycle to beep more times. Also you can use cronjob tu check the connectivity.

Also there is [beep](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/beep.1.html) but also check whether is in the blacklist

```
cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf | grep 'pcspkr'
```

If it's in the blacklist.conf file you have to uncomment that.

Comment: Well, `echo -e '\a'`, does not make any beep, but above follow up does make beep sound. Another issue is that i dont have internet and i have to have only alert based on ethernet interface eth0 or eth1 or wlan0